# WPF XAML Changing Image opacity on IsEnabled state

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, opacity, isenabled

I would like to have the image to have an opacity of .50 when the IsEnabled is false. I have been looking at multiple examples but still I am not able to grasp how to make it work.

Here is the full XAML of my custom control. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
<UserControl
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 mc:Ignorable="d"
 x:Class="test.StopButtonControl"
 x:Name="UserControl"
 d:DesignWidth="85" d:DesignHeight="85">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Image x:Name="StopButtonUI" Source="Images/stop.png" Stretch="Fill" MouseUp="StopButtonClick"/>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can couple the `Image`'s `Opacity` property to its `IsEnabled` property via a style trigger as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image x:Name="StopButtonUI" Source="Images/stop.png" >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

This will set the `Opacity` to 0.5 when `IsEnabled` is false.

The `Image`'s `IsEnabled` property will be triggered when the `UserControl` has its `IsEnabled` property  changed as a result of property inheritance i.e. the image is a child of the user control so it will have its `IsEnabled` property set too.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand and I will experiment with other properties.

Comment: I got caught out a little here with the range of `Opacity`. For anyone else who initially thought that the range would be from `0` to `100`, double check that you're actually using the range of `0` to `1` as demonstrated here else it will appear that nothing is changing.