# Change Image Source when IsEnabled is false

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to change an Image's Source property whenever the image is disabled/enabled.
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565483/wpf-xaml-changing-image-opacity-on-isenabled-state) out and that worked, whenever the image is disabled the opacity is changed. However, as soon as I try to set the Source property, it just does not work. It is ignored.
That's my markup:

```xaml
<Image Source="/My_Project;component/Images/countdown.png" Width="75">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/My_Project;component/Images/countdown.disabled.png"/> <!-- does not work -->
                    <!-- <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/> this works! -->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Am I missing something? Is it even possible to change the Source property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have 'hard coded' the `Image.Source` value when you declared your `Image`. You need to move that to the `Style` too. Try this:

```
<Image Width="75">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" 
                Value="/My_Project;component/Images/countdown.png"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" 
                        Value="/My_Project;component/Images/countdown.disabled.png"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

The reason for this is because WPF has many different ways to update a `DependencyProperty` and so has a [Dependency Property Value Precedence list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) which specifies which sources should be able to override changes made from other sources. According to this list, a local set value will override one set in a `Style Trigger`, but one set in a `Style Trigger` will override one set in a `Style Setter`.

Please refer to the linked page for further information on this.

Comment: I like your code formatting that avoids horizontal scrollbars :-)

Comment: We could do with automatic text wrapping on this website... it's well overdue. :)

Answer (score 2):

Due to [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) this will only work if you do not set a [local value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) for the `Source` property, but instead also set it via the Style:

```
<Image Width="75">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source"
                    Value="/My_Project;component/Images/countdown.png"/>    
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source"
                        Value="/My_Project;component/Images/countdown.disabled.png"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: LOL! Are we writing the same answer here? +1 for also mentioning the Dependency Property Value Precedence.

Comment: Great, thanks! @Sheridan sorry I can't mark your answer as accepted too, I just opted for the first one chronically :) Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @DavideDeSantis, I am more than happy for you to award the accepted answer to whomever you like, but for future reference only, we're supposed to award it to the *best* answer, not the *first* answer.

Comment: @Sheridan I know, and of course you are right. I was just thinking that you had basically written the same thing, but I read it again and your answer is a little bit more detailled than Clemens', so here you go, corrected :)

Comment: I didn't mean for you to change the accepted answer on *this* question... that's why I put *for future reference only* in my comment.